# Calculating image x and y

Tags: matrix, svg, inkscape

I imported image in `inkscape` and then i rotate that image and then i saved that svg document

and i got this in the document :

```
       .
       .

        <image
           y="-421.28461"
           x="335.27295"
           id="image2991"
           xlink:href="file:///C:/Users/tom/Documents/t.jpg"
           height="369"
           width="360"
           transform="matrix(0.22297057,0.97482518,-0.97482518,0.22297057,0,0)" />
       .
       .
```

Now at the time of saving the document if 1 can notice the value of **x** and **y** in inkscape editor (at its top menu) is different for the image object and when we saved the document and open it in notepad, the value is different. The value of `x` & `y` attributes which we see in the notepad is not the image object's actual `top-left` position. But when we open it in inkscape, the inkscape somehow calculate the correct value and place the image at correct position.

**Ques** : Now i just want to know how the inkscape calculate the correct `x` & `y` from the image attribute's `x` & `y` values?

**Note** : The image is rotated.

**EDIT**

[Take a look to this Post](http://inkscape.13.n6.nabble.com/text-object-rotation-amp-position-coordinates-x-and-y-values-td2818730.html), here `Bric` have posted the same problem which i am trying to explain you. May be this post will make you clear with the problem.

Comment: It's done via linear algebra, by applying the transformation stack to the point to compute its location in another space. For example, see [this demo](http://phrogz.net/svg/screen_location_for_element.xhtml) which transforms points within transformed spaces out to SVG and then into screen space.